# How can clean .CSV file before loading into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have many .CSV files which are stored into gcs and i want data from .CSV to the created table by using

```
bq load 'dataset.table' gs://path.csv schema
```

I have tried but always gives error

how can i remove unwanted value before importing a .CSV?

Comment: Hi @aarav and welcome to SO. Can you please tell us what error message are you getting and if you tried searching for some answer around this issue. There are few questions regarding this subject on SO amd very good Google documentiom which can guide you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The title of your question is unrelated with the actual question. Also, there is a typo in your command. Paths in Google Cloud Storage start with ‘gs://‘ not ‘gd://‘. In addition, you shouldn’t use quote marks when you specify the destination table. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_files_from) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you may have many CSV files no all of them matching one to one your destination table schema. One way to address it is to adjust the number of CSV fields, you can use serverless [Storage Mirror Recover settings](https://github.com/viant/smirror#payload-recover)
Another way to consider, given you have CSV files already in Google Cloud Storage, is serverless data ingestion with  [BqTail](https://github.com/viant/bqtail).

With BqTail you can specify a dedicated transient schema for your CSV fiels to finally ingest it to the destination table. Here is a [link](https://github.com/viant/bqtail/tree/master/e2e/regression/cases/019_transient_schema) an example of e2e test rule ingest CSV to a temp table and then to a final destination table.

Sometimes data quality is out of our control, in that case, I've been using BqTail to automatically detect corrupted files in batched Load jobs to send them to Storage Mirror Recovery to adjust and send it back for another Load job.